# Cannot change language back to english Fedora Core 14

Tags: fedora, language, fedora-14

I'm running Fedora 14, and I'm taking French is school so I decided to set my system to French to see how it was.

I edited /etc/sysconfig/i18n, and changed en_US to fr_FR. Then, I rebooted, and it switched to french.

I decided that I didn't know enough French to function, so I edited i18n again, and I rebooted. But it was still in French. Then this happened:

```
[Leo@chessman ~]$ cd /etc/sysconfig
[Leo@chessman sysconfig]$ su
Mot de passe : 
[root@chessman sysconfig]# cat i18n
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
[root@chessman sysconfig]#
```

Notice that after I typed in `su`, it said "mot de passe," which is French, even though it says LANG="en_US.UTF-8".

How can I change this back to English?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case the culprit was `/etc/profile` which had three `export` lines at the end (automatically added by a stupid hosting provider during server install).

Answer (score 0):

Everything is set in /etc/profile.d/lang.sh in Fedora and Red Hat based systems. See your $HOME/.i18n directory first.

If it does not help you can override this behavior in the /etc/profile.d/lang.sh file itself - put

```
export LANG=C
```

there.

There is also one more trick. Ssh client is configured to send locale environment variables by default. Try this:

```
LC_ALL=C ssh server
```

If it helps, edit your /etc/ssh/ssh_config (on the client side) or /etc/ssh/sshd_config (on the server side).

Comment: Adding one more trick!